# how to fix error gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the Gradle build system bundled with Android Studio. So far, I am able to build multi-project setups using dependencies that are stored in my project structure. when i build my project. i have a error:

```
Error:(37, 13) Failed to resolve: 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+' Show in FileShow in Project Structure 
Error:(37, 13) Failed to resolve: 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+' Show in FileShow in Project Structure
```

I try to insert mavenCentral(). but it's working:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vaeapp.gamecard.vn"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3.4"

        ndk {
            moduleName "gc"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/error-reporter.jar')
    //compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    // compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this inside your android tag:

```
android {
    //...
    //...
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    //...
}
```

Hope it helps you.